# integral de montecarlo en rstudio

Tags: r

integral de la esperanza de la distribución normal estándar en rstudio, implemente este código en r y no me da la estimación en el software.

```
integralz<-function(n, a, b){
   X<-runif(n,0,1)
   Y<- 2*(X*exp(-X^2/2)/sqrt(2*pi))
   Int<-sum(Y)/n

   list(Int)

   }
 integralz(100000,0,Inf)
```

Answer (score 2):

Hola Freddy el resultado no le da es porque usted esta utilizando, la distribución uniforme U ~ [0,1] y para intentar calcula una integral que se mueve entre -infinito e infinito como es el valor esperado de la distribución normal, por lo tanto no use la uniforme, utilice distribuciones continuas que tengan ese soporte como la normal estándar o la t-student.

Por ejemplo si quiero calcular la siguiente integral, de ∫ 5/(1+x^2) con x ϵ (-∞, ∞), utilizando el método de montecarlo. Entonces sea h(x) = 5/(1+x^2) y mi propuesta f(x) = N(0,1) la dist. normal estándar.

```
Integral_impropia <- function(h){
  h.aste <- function(x){h(x)*exp(0.5*x^2)}
  n <- 2500000
  set.seed(94)
  u <- rnorm(n)
  res <- sqrt(2*pi)*mean(h.aste(u))
  return(res)
}

h <- function(x){5/(1+x^2)}

integrate(h,-Inf,Inf)
15.70796 with absolute error < 2.6e-09

Integral_impropia(h)
[1] 15.61579
```

Ahora si quiere calcular el valor esperado de la distribución normal solo cambie h en el código.

```
h2 <- function(x){1/sqrt(2*pi)*x*exp(-x^2/2)}

integrate(h2,-Inf,Inf)
0 with absolute error < 0

Integral_impropia(h2)
[1] -0.0004724279
```